# Excel: I want to remove duplicate values in same row and many columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to delete duplicate values in same row and multiple column in excel...                   i want this

```
   A B C D E F G H I J K      RESULT
R1 8 0 1 8 1 5 8 1 9 5 5      80159
R2 7 8 7 7 4 5 0 7 6 8 9      78450689
R3 5 2 0 6 4 2 7 6 1 3 0      52064713
R4 4 3 5 0 7 2 5 3 2 4 8      4350728
```

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula:

```
=CONCAT(UNIQUE(A1:K1,TRUE))
```

[image]

---

If not then the assumption is that `0` will never be in the first column and that the data is as you provided, one number per cell:

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH(A1:K1,A1:K1,0)=COLUMN(A1:K1),A1:K1*{1;1}))),TRANSPOSE(10^(COUNT(MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH(A1:K1,A1:K1,0)=COLUMN(A1:K1),A1:K1*{1;1})))-TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNT(MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH(A1:K1,A1:K1,0)=COLUMN(A1:K1),A1:K1*{1;1})))))))))
```

Depending on ones version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If it is text or the numbers are more than one digit then vba will probably be needed.